# Posting Test results-report from a Selenium / TestNG back to TFS 2015

Tags: selenium, tfs, tfs-2015

We have a team writing Selenium Tests for a Web application. We have figured out how to create a "fake" build that can trigger the test, TFS will show if the test passed or failed. But what we want is to also post the html report in TFS as well.  What are people doing to keep the great reports that TestNG is creating?

Comment: You should be able to create a "real" Build that builds your Java project. From there, create a Release tied to that Build and use that to trigger your tests. TFS will roll up the results in it's Runs area that shows graphs and each individual result along with a history of failures (last release this test failed, etc). We use TFS instead of the reports generated by the library and never looked back.

Answer (score 1):

You can add them to a build as an Artefact using the REST API. that way you can download the report for local viewing. The "Upload test results" task in TFS 2018 and later as well as Azure DevOps can also upload HTML reports, though it will strip CSS and JavaScript for security purposes, rendering most reports ugly and useless.

These API's won't become available for older versions of TFS, your organisation will have to upgrade to Azure DevOps Server 2019 (formerly TFS, out soon) or migrate to Azure DevOps to get these new features.

See also:

- [Upload and associate build artefact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/build/artifacts/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)
- [Create test run attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/create%20test%20run%20attachment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)
- [Create test result attachments](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/test/attachments/create%20test%20result%20attachment?view=azure-devops-rest-5.0)